# Why is only Linux affected by the Bay Trail cstate bug?

Tags: kernel, cpu

I recently tried to install Linux (I tried Ubuntu and Arch) on a system using a Pentium N3510 (Bay Trail) processor and initially failed with random hangs and sluggishness. Trying out various things, I found that there are two things that can fix this: [One option](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=109051) is setting the kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=1`. The other option, which is probably better, is to disable reporting of the availability of the C6 state to the OS in the BIOS.

As far as I found out there is a bug in [some CPUs](https://askubuntu.com/a/803649/246170) that leads to crashes (or apparently sluggishness in my case) when the CPU is instructed to go to power state C6 while an ISR is being handled. Since my problem is fixed by those settings, I assume I am affected by this bug.

Now I wonder, why does Windows run properly on those systems? Is it about the way that ISRs and power states are handled in Linux vs Windows? Are the Kernel developers lacking some knowledge? Is the bug so new that it just hasn't been fixed? Are there not enough affected systems to properly test it? (The problem and its fix were very obvious in my case.)